# Swap any two cells using excel VBA - including non-adjacent cells

Tags: excel, vba, cell

I need to swap two cell values. Holding `Shift Key` then pick & drop method don't work here. so I decided to create a macro in which I can get Active cell address by

```
ActiveCell.Address
```

but how can I get address of the cell which I had copied before running this macro?
to elaborate more these are the steps to swap values.

> Copy a cell
>
> Select another cell in the same sheet
>
> Run Macro to swap values (which will save activecell value as string and paste the copied cell value)

**Updated:** *For Switching Columns, Cells or Rows using VBA in less than Three steps please follow this https://youtu.be/MaiSBVguh28*

Comment: Explained here.  https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/swap-values.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sub will do the trick:

```
Sub swapper()
Dim cellfirst As String, cellsecond As String
If Not Selection.Cells.Count = 2 Then
    MsgBox ("Please only select two cells")
        Else
        If Selection.Areas.Count > 1 Then
            cellfirst = Selection(1).Value
            cellsecond = Selection.Areas(2).Value
            Selection(1).Value = cellsecond
            Selection.Areas(2).Value = cellfirst
                Else
                cellfirst = Selection(1).Value
                cellsecond = Selection(2).Value
                Selection(1).Value = cellsecond
                Selection(2).Value = cellfirst
        End If
End If
End Sub
```

It will test if two cells are selected, if not give an error message. Then it will test if the cells are apart or close together. Then based on that store the values of both cells in strings, swap the strings, and print back to cell.

Note: Select two different cells by holding `ctrl` and clicking on both cells.

I realise this isn't 1 for 1 what you've asked for, but why go through the effort of copying something yourself when you can have the macro do it all for you?

Comment: Yes! you are right about " why go through the effort of copying" as it could be achieve through 4 steps. select 1st cell>> copy>> select 2nd cell >> Run the macro.
your answer (best-way so far), there are 3 steps to follow. select 1st cell>> select 2nd cell>> Run the macro.

Comment: can you explain, when code will go to second `else` statement??

Comment: @IbneAshiq the second if statement detects whether the two cells you have selected are directly adjacent. If so, there is only one area selected, and runs cell 1 and 2 from that area. However this won't work if the cells are apart on the sheet, which then won't be cell 1 and 2, but area 1 cell 1, area 2 cell 1. The if statement counts the amount of areas, and handles it either as two areas or two adjacent cells.